# Trying to establish the following identity involving sums using residues

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, contour-integration

If $2z - 1 $ is not an integer, then

$$ \frac{1}{\cos( \pi z) } = 1 + \frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{ 2z -1}{(2z-1)^2-4n^2} + \frac{4}{1-4n^2} \right]$$

################Attempt################.

I consider $f(z) = \frac{1}{\cos \pi z} -1 = \frac{ 1 - \cos \pi z}{\cos \pi z}$. We know $\cos \pi z = 0 \iff \pi z = (2n +1) \frac{ \pi}{2} \iff z = n + \frac{1}{2}$. So $f(z) $ has simple poles at $a_n = n + \frac{1}{2} $. The residues at $z = a_n$ are given by $b_n = (-1)^n $ and consider square $C_k$ with corners $ \pm k \pm ki $. Then by residue theorem

$$ \int_{C_k} f(z) dz = 2 \pi i \sum_{n= - \infty}^{\infty} \{ b_n : b_n \in C_n \} $$

But, then I feel like this wont lead me anywhere. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Use Fourier Series.

Comment: I am not allowed to use fourier. Only residues techniques :S

Comment: Alternately, differentiate the natural logarithm of [Euler's infinite product formula for the sine function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).

Comment: No offense, but I provided you already with an answer, which is that the above relation is wrong.  I also provided the correct relation, which was verified in Mathematica v 9.0.  What "credible" source are you looking for?

Comment: Hello Gordon, I dont think it is a typo. I consulted the errata of the book and this is not listed as an error and also this is a third edition book. Also, I dont see where you used the fact that $2z - 1 $ is not an integer.

Comment: I used that fact inherently in evaluating the cotangent at the poles of $f$. If there is no error cited inthe book, then check the problem again to see that you reproduced it correctly.  I am certain of my result.

Comment: I agree with @RonGordon, take the limite as $z$ approaches $1/2$ and the right side will be finite while the left side becomes un bounded. If this an exercise from the book, then it is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to prove is that

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} f(n) = -\sum_k \operatorname*{Res}_{\zeta=\zeta_k} \left [\pi \, \cot{(\pi \zeta)} \, f(\zeta)\right ] $$

where $\zeta_k$ are the non-integer poles of $f$.  You do this by showing that

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \oint_{C_N} d\zeta \, \pi \, \cot{(\pi \zeta)} \, f(\zeta) = 0$$

on the square $C_N$ with vertices $(\pm N \pm 1/2 )(1+i)$.

Once you show that, then you can evaluate

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \left [\frac{2 z-1}{(2 z-1)^2-4 n^2} + \frac{4}{1-4 n^2} \right ] = \frac{\pi}{4} \sum_k \operatorname*{Res}_{\zeta=\zeta_k} \left ( \cot{(\pi \zeta)} \,  \left [\frac{2 z-1}{\zeta^2-(z-1/2)^2} + \frac{4}{\zeta^2-1/4} \right ]\right ) $$

where $\zeta_{1,2} = \pm (z-1/2)$.  (Note that singularities at $\zeta=\pm 1/2$ are removable.)  Thus, the double infinite sum is equal to

$$\frac{\pi}{4} [-\tan{(\pi z)}] \left (1+\frac{4}{z(z-1)} \right ) + \frac{\pi}{4} \tan{(\pi z)} \left (-1+\frac{4}{z(z-1)} \right )= -\frac{\pi}{2} \tan{(\pi z)}$$

The sum, however, is also equal to $2 S + 4 + \frac1{2 z-1} $.  Thus,

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left [\frac{2 z-1}{(2 z-1)^2-4 n^2} + \frac{4}{1-4 n^2} \right ] = -\frac12 \left [\frac{\pi}{2} \tan{(\pi z)} + 4 + \frac1{2 z-1} \right ]$$

This agrees with numerical results I derived in Mathematica.  I am not sure where your result comes from, but it is not correct.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. The result is actually an exercise in marsden's Basic complex analysis book. I dont think it is a typo.

Comment: Ron, You were right! it was a typo. I am sorry for not believing you, but I will award you the bounty. Thanks so much!